# Физическое движение объекта при движении мышкой

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужна помощь в написании кода физического движения объекта по оси x в зависимости от изменения положения пальца игрока на телефоне.

Нефизическое движение написал, но требуется физическое, так как в игре много коллайдеров!

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    startPos = Input.mousePosition;

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    Vector3 newPose = startPos - Input.mousePosition;
    startPos = Input.mousePosition;
 
    X = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x - newPose.x * sensitivity, xLeftBorder, xRightBorder);
 
    transform.position = new Vector3(X, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: а что если пускать из места клика луч и куда попал луч двигать объект. genius

Comment: Что-то сложное. Лишняя операция

Comment: Это единственное решение твоего вопроса)

Comment: Там где ты кликаешь пальцем пускает луч относительно ScreenToWorldPoint, потом считыватешь где луч коснулся земли и туда уже толкаешь свой объект

Comment: Вопрос скорее в том как толкать. Пытаюсь через rigidbody.AddForce, но пока не получается

Comment: используй `Vector3.MoveTowards()`